# getting the data from DB and export into .CSV usig pymongo

Tags: pymongo

> **
>
> 1. i am getting cursor object and not get the data from db. here is the
>      code with output  I need help on that and i alos post the output ;
>
> **
>   when i was try to get the output it will give the cursor object and i was try to get the data from db and export complete code into csv into that code i used aggregate funcction for pymongo.

```
    import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient 
import json
import time
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
starttime = time.time()
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),"%Y-%m-%d")
# print(today)
#connect to database
client = MongoClient()
x= []
docs = pd.DataFrame(columns=[])
with client:
    db = client['local']
    col= db.daily_dim_appname_cdn 
     Total_Bandwidth = float(uncache) + float(cache)
     Actual_Internet_Bandwidth == uncache
     Peak_Bandwidth = uncache + cache
    cursor = list(col.find({},{"recorddate":1,"cdn":1,"tp":1}))
#     print(cursor)
    for i in cursor:
        if i['cdn'] == 'Internet':
            uncache = col.aggregate([
{'$project':{'year': { '$year': "$recorddate" },'month': {' $month': "$recorddate" },"day":{"$dayOfMonth":"$recorddate" },'cdn':1,'tp':1,'recorddate':1}},
{'$match':{"year" :2020,'month':1,'day':10,'tp':{'$gt':0},'cdn':{'$in':['Internet']}}},
{'$group' : {'_id': '$recorddate', 'sumtp': { '$sum' : '$tp' }}},
{'$project':{'_id':0,'rdate':'$_id','sumtp':{'$divide':['$sumtp',1000000000]},'rmonth': { '$month': "$_id" }}},
])
            print("uncache",uncache)


        elif i['cdn'] != 'Internet':
            cache= col.aggregate([
{'$project':{'year': { '$year': "$recorddate" },'month': {' $month': "$recorddate" },'cdn':1,'tp':1,'recorddate':1}},
{'$match':{"year" :2020,'month':1,'tp':{'$gt':0},'cdn':{'$nin':['Internet']}}},
{'$group' : {'_id': '$recorddate', 'sumtp': { '$sum' : '$tp' }}},
{'$project':{'_id':0,'rdate':'$_id','sumtp':{'$divide':['$sumtp',1000000000]},'rmonth': { '$month': "$_id" }}},
])
            print("cache",cache)




output:


cache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x113180278>
cache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x1131802b0>
uncache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x113180438>
uncache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x1131802e8>
uncache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x113180358>
uncache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x1131804e0>
uncache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x113180278>
uncache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x113180208>
uncache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x113180240>
uncache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x113180438>
cache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x113180470>
uncache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x1131802e8>
cache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x113180358>
cache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x1131804e0>
uncache <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x113180278>





enter code here
```

Comment: What you have in cursor? Share output of the cursor.

Comment: If you `list(find(...))` you defeat the purpose of `find` returning a cursor by trying to bring the complete result set into memory.

Comment: The `aggregate` command returns a https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html which you must itterate over with a for loop to get results.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to iterate over cache and uncache. Like:

```
for i in cache:
    print(i)
    break
```

I hope you will get data from `i['key']`.